# keras (tensorflow backend) run on a cluster using slurm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cluster-computing, slurm

I have the opportunity to run my Tensorflow training on a cluster computer with slurm workload manager (the cluster contains nearly 400000 cores, 40000 GB of RAM, Performance is Rmax=500 TFlop/s and Rpeak=1000 TFlop/s, AMD GPUs).

I work on image processing projects using deep learning algorithms.

My question is how to scale my keras deep learning to run on this cluster using slurm as workload manager ?

Comment: It depends on the specific type of GPU. Your bottleneck will be your data pipeline. So have a close look on tf.dataset.

Comment: I will use the CPU version of Tensorflow. Using Tensorflow on MD GPU may be complicated.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed

Comment: But I am currently familiar with keras. Is there any possibility for using keras.

Comment: Keras doesn't have any distributed support, in the end since TF is a backend to Keras, only TF matters here.

Answer (score 2):

Use Horovod to scale out the Keras training - https://github.com/uber/horovod